# Merging two arrays non concatenative, from two seperate arrays, but with 1 common variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to merge two arrays in a specific way, but cannot find the right syntax to do this.

```
primaryData = [1,2]
secondaryData = [3,4]
label = [label1, label2]
```

Currently this works

```
         data = $.map(labels, function(v, i) {

            return [[" " + v, " " + primaryData[i], " " + secondaryData[i]]] ;

        });
```

And gives me output of:

```
[["label1", "1"], ["label2", "2"]]
```

So two arrays in an array.

However I want this:

```
[["label1", "1"], ["label2", "2"], ["label1", "3"], ["label2", "4"]]
```

So basically doing the same thing twice with "labels" and then add numbers from two different sources.

I have tried this:

```
         data = $.map(labels, function(v, i) {

            return [[" " + v, " " + primaryData[i]], [" " + v, " " + secondaryData[i]]];

        });
```

But that provides me with:

```
[["label1", "1"], ["label1", "3"], ["label2", "2"], ["label2", "4"]]
```

So it seems like the arrays are merging in a concatenative way. Using + instead of a comma separation does not create 2 arrays in an array, but 2 objects in an array.

Comment: post your input arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could concat `primaryData` and `secondaryData` and map then the value of `label` with the remainder operator and the value of the iterating array.

```js
var primaryData = [1, 2],
    secondaryData = [3, 4],
    label = ['label1', 'label2'],
    result = primaryData.concat(secondaryData).map(function(a, i) {
        return [label[i % 2], a.toString()];
    });
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple for loop"

```js
var data = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  data.push(["label" + (i % 2 + 1), (i + 1).toString()]);
} 

console.log(data);
```

Comment: This is hard to do with the other arrays. Or I simply cant see how you'd do that:                    data2.push([labels + (i % 2 + primaryData), (secondaryData).toString()]);

Comment: This will get you the required results without the arrays. If you need the arrays, use @NinaScholz's answer.

Comment: My question was based on the arrays, but thank you, Ninas works as intended :)